# Quickest way from Istanbul to Krakow

Tags: berlin, istanbul, krakow

I must travel to Krakow for a meeting, but I'm really short on time. I would leave from Istanbul at 8PM and I must be in Krakow by following day, 9AM. There is no direct flight between Istanbul and Krakow, and other flight's departure time is not helping.

I considered going Berlin first, then finding a way to Krakow, but I'm not sure if I can be in there just in time.

Comment: What about flying to Vienna and then rent a car and drive to Krakow?

Comment: I just checked that option - there are no flights to Vienna after 8 pm

Comment: @AleksG: There is one *at* 8PM though, TK 1889.

Comment: @NateEldredge Hm, very interesting.  The [full time table](http://www.ataturkairport.com/tr-TR/Ucus_Bilgileri/Documents/UcusTarifesi.pdf) of the Istanbul airport lists as as leaving 1at 19:45.

Comment: Krakow! Krakow! Two direct hits!

Comment: If time constraints are key and budget isn't a constraint charter a plane.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming your trip is very soon, Turkish Airlines flight 1889 departs Istanbul at 8:00 PM and arrives Vienna at 9:20 PM.

From Vienna, you could rent a car and drive to Krakow (4.5 hours).  Or, if you can get to Wien Westbahnhof by 10:12 pm, there is an overnight train ([D 406](http://www.oebb.at/en/Travelling_abroad/SparSchiene_Europa/Poland/Timetable_Vienna-Krakow/index.jsp)) arriving Krakow at 6:36 AM.

Comment: Interestingly, [Istanbul airport timetable](http://www.ataturkairport.com/tr-TR/Ucus_Bilgileri/Documents/UcusTarifesi.pdf) lists this flight as leaving at 7:45 pm, not at 8 pm.

Comment: I found a flight leaves 6.40 PM from Istanbul and arrives nearly 8.20 PM. Since I started working near SAW airport, I could take this flight. What opportunities do I have to travel from airport to Westbahnhof? I'll probably use this way to travel. So I'm marking as answered. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Having spent about an hour looking at many possible combinations, the only way I found for you to make it in time is to fly to Berlin (there's Pegasus Airline flight 7854, leaving Istanbul at 22:55 and arriving to Berlin at 00:45 local time).  Then hire a car at the airport and drive straight to Krakow.  The drive is about 6 hours and through the night you shouldn't encounter much traffic.

If you add about an hour in Belin airport, this should put you in Krakow right about 8 am.

There are some easier options if you can leave Istanbul earlier (i.e. flights around 19:30 or so), but then you have to be at the airport in Istanbul no later than 18:30.

Comment: @pnuts: I don't know Istanbul and its traffic, and I'm aware it has fewer bridges than a naive visitor expects, but are you basically saying that 2 hours (2000 start until 2200 checkin for 2255 flight) isn't long enough to cross the Bosphorus and cover the 22 miles by taxi or whatever? Naturally, any trip this tight is going to leave a *reasonable* chance of being stranded hundreds of miles from destination, but is it just totally implausible to get out of Istanbul on the Asian side in 2 hours?

Comment: ... hmm, Google maps says "47 minutes without traffic" from its generic Istanbul location in  the extreme south-east of the European side. And I imagine there's traffic, so I'm starting to see what you mean ;-)